# permission denied for deleting image using unlink in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a code that i use to delete an image from folder and then i got a problem that i cant get a permission to unlink this file.

**here is the warning message**

> Message: unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\gimbot\gambar/): Permission denied

**here is my code**

```
private function hapusGbr($id){
    $image = $this->db->get_where('artikel',array('id'=>$id))->row();

    unlink(FCPATH."gambar/".$image[0]['image']);
}
```

Comment: Check folder permission,

Comment: you are using `row()`, so you should use as `$image->image`, also check for permission of folder

Answer (score 0):

You dont have right permissions set on your folder. 
Kindly change permission like this in your code:

```
chmod(FCPATH."gambar", 775);
private function hapusGbr($id){
    $image = $this->db->get_where('artikel',array('id'=>$id))->row();

    unlink(FCPATH."gambar/".$image['image']);
}
```

Comment: using `->row()` does `[0]` needed ? it should be as `$image->image`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra yup it is not required, i have updated the answer.

Comment: It is possible that `chown` will fail if `unlink` fails, because the web server running php doesn't have write access or ownership access to the parent directory at `FCPATH`. You may need to do the `chown` from a super user shell.

Comment: if i use '$image->image' it show me an error  "trying to get property of non-object", and the file still cant be deleted

Comment: @kevin my bad, I have updated the answer. Use $image['image'] instead.

Comment: so, i must to place 'chown' outside of function ? because i get an error that said "ParseError" unexpected 'chown'

Comment: @Kevin I am really sorry it should have been chmod() instead of chown as chown defines the owner and chmod () is used for changing permissions.

Comment: im sorry, but it doesnt change anything when i tried. i still get the permission denied error

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: I am asking which server (Apache, IIS,nginx etc)??

Comment: ohh, i using apache in xampp

Answer (score 0):

I think your file path is wrong. Please try something hard coded for xampp.

```
public function hapusGbr($id){
       $image = $this->db->get_where('artikel',array('id'=>$id))->row();
        $file = FCPATH."gambar/".$image->image;


        $folder = 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\yoursite\youruploadfolder';
        chown($folder,777);
        unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/gambar/$image->image");

}
```